# Sending messages from remote git repo on push

Tags: git

Usually when I push to a git repo I get output like this

```
$ git push origin somefeature
Counting objects: 42, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (42/42), done.
Writing objects: 100% (42/42), 13.39 MiB | 2.69 MiB/s, done.
Total 42 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
To github.com:greggman/someproject.git
 * [new branch]      somefeature -> somefeature
```

But, sometime in the few months when I push to github I see these `remote:` messages.

```
$ git push origin somefeature
Counting objects: 42, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (42/42), done.
Writing objects: 100% (42/42), 13.39 MiB | 2.69 MiB/s, done.
Total 42 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (5/5), completed with 5 local objects.
remote: 
remote: Create a pull request for 'somefeature' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/greggman/someproject/pull/new/somefeature
remote: 
To github.com:greggman/someproject.git
 * [new branch]      somefeature -> somefeature
```

How do I accomplish this with my own git repos? Like for example

```
remote: Hello World
```

To put it another way, say I setup a public repo that you ssh to at `ssh://freerepos.com`. You type

```
git clone ssh://freerepos.com/some/repo.git
```

then make some changes, commit them, and type

```
git push origin master
```

How do I configure my repo so it prints

```
remote: Hello World
```

in your terminal when you push to my machine the same way github is currently inserting remote output when I push to their machines?

Comment: These messages seem to be coming from [github itself](https://blog.github.com/changelog/2018-09-10-pull-request-url-output-in-the-command-line/), for all repos..

Comment: Yes they are coming from github but I'm using git locally so git clearly has some protocol to allow the remote side to send messages back to local. My question is how to take advantage of that protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done using [server-side git hooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

> Both standard output and standard error output are forwarded to git send-pack on the other end, so you can simply echo messages for the user.

Answer (score 0):

adding a `post-update` hook does this

```
cat > .git/hooks/post-update
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello world"
```

results in

```
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 245 bytes | 245.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: hello world
To /Users/me/temp/delme-git/pub-repo
   deae6fa..4d3d769  master -> master
```